# Removing the last character of a tuple list inside a 'for' loop?

Tags: python

```
for start_index in range(0, len(bravo_uncode_message),q):
    new_list.extend(bravo_uncode_message[start_index:start_index + q])
    new_list.append('0')
```

I couldn't be able to delete the last 0 that I append to my tuple list iI have tried `new_list.pop()` and `new_list[:-1]` and it works but it also deletes 64 more strings that I had and the number of strings is 128.

```
import binascii

response=raw_input("Decrypt a message or encrypt a message? D/E : ")
if response== "E":
    message_to_encrypt=raw_input("Introduce message to encrypt: ")
    key= raw_input("Insert key:")
    abc=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    if any(word in key for word in abc):
        print 'Not a valid key...'
    elif len(key)!= 7:
        print 'Invalid key'
    else:
        key=key*len(message_to_encrypt)
        binary_message = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message_to_encrypt), 16))
        print binary_message
        binary_message= list(binary_message)
        del binary_message[0]
        print binary_message
        del binary_message[0]
        recovery_number = binary_message[0]
        print binary_message
        del binary_message[8 - 1::8]
        print binary_message
        binary_message = ''.join(map(str,binary_message))
        print binary_message
        print key
        a = binary_message
        b = key
        xored_message= int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
        print bin(xored_message)[2:].zfill(len(a))
        print message_to_encrypt
elif response== "D":
    encrypted_message = raw_input("Introduce message to decrypt: ")
    beta_uncode_message = [tuple(map(int, format(i, '07b'))) for i in range(128)]
    g=len(encrypted_message)/7
    n=0
    for i in beta_uncode_message:
        n=n+1
        if n<129:
            alpha_uncode_message=beta_uncode_message[n-1]*g
            x=tuple(map(str,alpha_uncode_message))
            alpha_uncode_message=x
            a=encrypted_message
            b=alpha_uncode_message
            b=''.join(map(str,b))
            charlie_uncode_message = int(a, 2) ^ int(b, 2)
            bravo_uncode_message=bin(charlie_uncode_message)[2:].zfill(len(a))
            new_list = []
            q = 7
            for start_index in range(0, len(bravo_uncode_message),q):
                new_list.extend(bravo_uncode_message[start_index:start_index + q])
            new_list.append('0')
            bravo_uncode_message = new_list
            bravo_uncode_message = ''.join(map(str, bravo_uncode_message))
            binary_axis = '0b'
            bravo_uncode_message = binary_axis + bravo_uncode_message
            print bravo_uncode_message
            k = int(bravo_uncode_message, 2)
            uncode_message = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % k)
            print uncode_message
            if n>129:
                break
        else:
            break
```

Above is my code. The first part is the where I have a problem with when using `new_list.pop()` and `new_list[:-1]` — `bravo_uncode_message` loses 64 strings.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you want. You have asked 3 question on tuples already. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: We will also need to know what `bravo_uncode_message` is

Comment: I just what to delete the las 0 but seems impossible doing it with out loosing half of my string

Comment: On examining the full code you added, is `new_list.append('0')` a part of the `for-loop` or outside of it? In the first half, it is part of the loop, while in the full code it is outside of the loop. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Convert the binary string to int:

```
new_list = int(new_list, 2);
```

Then run `new_list[:-1]`

Afterward, convert `new_list` back to binary:

```
new_list = bin(new_list)
```

I haven't tried this code, I hope it works.

Comment: Before you append `0`, convert the Unicode list to a list of strings first and try again.

Comment: How? I am really stuck at this

Comment: On examining the full code you added, is `new_list.append('0')` a part of the `for-loop` or outside of it? In the first half, it is part of the loop, while in the full code it is outside of the loop. Please clarify.

Comment: Part of it thats the problem

Comment: Please try out my updated answer, let me know how it goes.